# SQL query for game rental website - game delivery report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2da70/13

I am creating a game rental website using MS SQL 08 and I have to create a report which will give me a list of all the games that need to be posted and to who.

This query will have to go through different stages:-

1. List the users that have not reached their game quota for that month based on the subscription package they have chosen and rental table.
2. Compare this list of users to their favourites list and asign a game to them based on what game is their highest priority and by date.
3. The game or games selected must be in stock which needs compared to quantity levels in games table.

I have a SQL query but it is not taking into consideration the dates that a user added a game to their favourites list, it works solely on priority level.  I need to change this query so it picks the oldest date added if the priority of the games are the same.  In this sample data in SQL Fiddle it should be giving me barcode 27 to match with Need for Speed Rivals but it is giving me FIFA 14 as it is the first favourite record it sees.

Also the report needs to show more than the game barcode, it needs to show user name and game details.  It is also only working for a single user at the moment with with me entering a user ID manually but it should just go through all users.

If anyone can help me with this query it would be much appreicated it, just really dont know where to go from here.

Comment: show us what you have done so far...

Comment: @logixologist, see the posted fiddle.

Comment: do add the right tag(s) to better the chances of getting a right answer.

Comment: @Rahul sorry wasnt sure which tag to choice, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Can anyone provide any more help with this, I dont know how to ammend the query so it doesnt need me to manually type in user ID.  It should just go through all users.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
ORDER BY Favourites.Priority
```

to

```
ORDER BY Favourites.Priority, Favourites.DatePicked asc
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect :) .. Any idea getting a full report not having to manually enter user ID?

Comment: I'd add a row number partitioned by user id, then more the logic in top into another join and match up where the row number <= rentability from that top section.

Comment: Thanks Andreas I will give that a go now, might need your help with some of the sql to it if you wouldnt mind.

Comment: With a nice, complete sqlfiddle, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Brilliant thanks :) .. I'll work on this one I have and get it tidyied up and post an uptodate sqlfiddle.  I wish SQLFiddle allowed more than 8000 characters.

Comment: you can remove the schema prefix and braces through most of the document. Might buy you a little space. Also the billing table is unused in the query.

Comment: Thanks good idea, I have reduced it a good bit now, what all do you think needs done to it to make it more workable?  Are if it suits better i could get you the database mdf file its only 2MB.  Sorry to put you to so much trouble just I really dont have a clue I got this far by luck.