# SQL Customer leave before trail ends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help making a SQL query for a game rental site, I need to know the customers who leave before their trial ends.

So the query will only involve the Users table and I have to do a query like:-

```
Select Users
FROM Users
WHERE Dateleft is less than 30 days from date jointed.
```

Database is MS SQL 2008.

What I have so far is:-

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (Dateleft >= Datejoined - 30)
```

But it doesn't work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2da70/14

Comment: How does this question get so many upvotes ?

Comment: Because people are nice, its a Friday night :)

Comment: Great ! Nice time for people to get some drinks.

Comment: Exactly :) .. Now your talking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the DATEDIFF function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i've looked at that but dont really understand how it will work for this situation.  Yes it will tell me the difference in dates but if i just want to compare two fields in a table for all the users and give me all the users who left, how does that work?

Comment: SELECT User_ID, FirstName, LastName, Password, Email, ContactNum, Address, County, Gender, Datejoined, Dateleft, Subscription_ID
FROM     Users
WHERE  datediff(dd,Dateleft,Datejoined)<=30

Comment: Thats brilliant @Leparevilo I just had to change dateleft,datejoined the other way around and its 100% Thanks so much really apprecaite it.  If you fancy something ALOT harder you could have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256377/sql-query-for-game-rental-website-game-delivery-report

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Dateleft < DATEADD(dd,30,Datejoined)
```

Comment: Thanks, is DateAdd todays date?  Whereas I need it to be datajoined.  I need to be able to see all the users who left before 30 days from datejoined.